# Whats wrong with my code? My identifier isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, css

The word yo won't pop up in bold or red. Where is the error located? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>
My cool website
</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>

#mybluewords{
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 50px;
}
</style>

<p id-"mybluewords">
Yo 
</p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `id-""` would be the issue.... maybe try using equals? `id=""`

Comment: learn how to use online code validators or ones built into IDE's

Comment: @charlietfl - we've all been there... It's easy to miss a single character after hours of staring at a screen.

Comment: @Lix oh yeah haven't we!!  But there are tools that will help and knowing about them is a good thing .... give a man a fish, or teach a man to fish

Comment: @charlietfl - its a **great** thing to know of and how to use tools like this - I agree! I felt you original comment was a little snarky, that is what prompted my comment. A link to a validator that you like would have been the "teaching" part here.

Comment: Hi @james, Here is a very useful tool that will validate your HTML for you and let you know of any issues that are found - https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. It **did** find the issue you are dealing with here (the `id` property)

Answer (score 3):

Replace the dash with an equal sign, that it looks like this:

```
<p id="mybluewords">
Yo 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

check equalto: 
id **=**

```
<p id="mybluewords">
Yo 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning your tag ID must check with equal ,

```
<p id="mybluewords">
Yo 
</p>
```

For your reference,
Syntax

```
id     Specifies a unique id for the element.
```

Naming rules:

- Must contain at least one character.
- Must not contain any space characters.
- In HTML, all values are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Use an equal sign instead of a dash:

```
<p id="mybluewords">
yo
</p>
```

Not a dash.